# How to scrape a web table in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to **scrape** data contained in the table from this url :

```
url <- "http://mlb.mlb.com/stats/sortable.jsp#elem=%5Bobject+Object%5D&tab_level=child&click_text=Sortable+Player+hitting&game_type='R'&season=2018&season_type=ANY&league_code='MLB'&sectionType=sp&statType=hitting&page=1&ts=1567176051240&playerType=QUALIFIER&sportCode='mlb'&split=&team_id=&active_sw=&position=&page_type=SortablePlayer&sortOrder='desc'&sortColumn=avg&results=&perPage=50&timeframe=&last_x_days=&extended=0"
```

i tried using  below code in R :

```
library(rvest)
library(xml2)

data <- read_html(url)

hitting2018 <- data %>%
      html_nodes("table") %>%
      html_table(fill=TRUE) %>%
      .[[1]]                      # because is the only table 
hitting2018
```

after run the code , r shows me  : `Error in .[[1]] : subscript out of bounds`

Any help or idea scraping the data  is going to be appreciated,

Comment: What happens when you run that code up to the point of calling `html_table` but without the indexing?

Comment: it runs successfully without the indexing   but when  i run the last part of the code up  , r shows me : `Error in hitting2018(.) : could not find function "hitting2018"`

Comment: You probably deleted the `.[[1]]` but not the pipe preceding it. I mean see if you get a table when you call everything until and including `html_table`

Comment: yes, you  are right i deleted the `[[1]]` , i didn't get a table  until that point  `html_table` r shows `NULL (empty)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That info is dynamically loaded. You can see this by turning off javascript in the browser - the table is not loaded. You can monitor the web traffic, via dev tools <kbd>F12</kbd>,  when refreshing the page <kbd>F5</kbd> and see the source xhr request (which returns json).

You can make a call to this url direct and parse json

```
library(jsonlite)

data <- jsonlite::read_json("http://mlb.mlb.com/pubajax/wf/flow/stats.splayer?season=2018&sort_order='desc'&sort_column='avg'&stat_type=hitting&page_type=SortablePlayer&game_type='R'&player_pool=QUALIFIER&season_type=ANY&sport_code='mlb'&results=1000&recSP=1&recPP=50", simplifyVector = T)
print(data$stats_sortable_player$queryResults$row)
```

Comment: Super , it works !     , Thank you so much for your help  =)